# What does it mean by the sentence with '#'

Tags: python-3.x

```
 words = ['item','em','tem']
 words = list(set(words))
 Trie = lambda: collections.defaultdict(Trie) #
                                        ^
 trie = Trie()
 nodes = [reduce(dict.__getitem__, word[::-1], trie) for word in words] #
                 ^
```

The purpose of this code is create a trie-tree.

But I get confused on the 'dict.**getitem**' and the 'Trie' in the sentence fragment: 'collections.defaultdict(Trie)'.

What does it mean? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You can use single backquotes (\`) to format code references properly, like this `dict.__getitem__`.